# In Ruby, how can I maintain a long list of instance variables from a file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

For example I store a lot of instance variables in a YAML file. This allow me to change the state of the program while it is running. However I need to change the method that reads the file every time I add a new variable.

e.g.

```
config = YAML.open_file 'config.yml'
@var1 = config["var1"]
@var2 = config["var2"]
@var3 = config["var3"]
@var4 = config["var4"]
@var5 = config["var5"]
...
```

How can I make this more dynamic and not need to change it as I add variables in the YAML file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Ruby meta-programming!

`instance_variable_set` is your friend here:

```
config = YAML.load_file 'config.yml'
config.each do |key,value|
  instance_variable_set('@'+key, value)
end
```

#### Test:

```
puts @var1
```

Comment: See Ruby docs for it here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set

Also worth a look at some of the other methods there if you're interested in this question, particularly the getter `#instance_variable_get` and `#instance_variables`